# CakePHP3: cannot display a virtual field in a Form

Tags: cakephp-3.4

In a `beforeMarshall()`, I create an additionnal field in my entity.
In my controller, I `debug($myEntity)` just before assigning the data to the view, and I see my field.
I even created a getter like follow:

```
protected function _getTmpImage() {

    if (isset($this->_properties['tmp_image'])) {
        debug($this->_properties['tmp_image']);
        return $this->_properties['tmp_image'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and In my view, I see the corresponding `debug()` display.

But the follwing line:

```
<?= $this->Form->hidden('agpoi_images.'.$key.'.tmp_image'); ?>
```

desesperately creates the following html code:

```
<input name="agpoi_images[0][tmp_image]" class="form-control" value="" type="hidden">
```

Can you tell me why?

PS: I also tried to add the following statement in my entity class, even if I think I don't have to do that according to [the doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-properties)

```
class MyEntity extends Entity
{

    protected $_virtual = ['tmp_image'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In view file, when using form elements, the `$fieldname` must be of the form ‘Modelname.fieldname’ which makes cakephp easy to substitute controller data and to send the post request in such format.

In your case, you can create the hidden form field in the same way `$this->Form->hidden(‘MyEntity.tmp_image)` which will be displayed as

```
<input name=“MyEntity[tmp_image]" class="form-control" value=“<tmp_image_value>" type="hidden">
```

Comment: I think It's what I did, but as it belongs to an array, `$key` must be there.

Comment: By array, did you mean the entity object as a whole or your virtual field tmp_image?

Comment: I mean that I reaaly access to an array of `agpoi_images` with a `tmp_image` field of each of them. I access to other fields like that.

Comment: Then, you can access it in a forloop like `foreach ($agpoi_images as $index => $agpoi_image) {echo $this->Form->hidden('agpoi_images.' . $index . '.tmp_image', ['value' => $agpoi_image->tmp_image]);}`

Comment: Ok Roger that works but I wonder why I have to specify the value field, That automatically works for the other ones. Maybe because it doesn't really belongs to the entity....

Comment: Cakephp will implicitly populate form values using view [ContextProvider](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.View.Form.ContextInterface.html) which detects entity object automatically.But in this case, its an array of entity objects and therefore we have to explicitly provide the value.

Comment: I don't really agree other entity fields accessed in the exact same way doesn't cause any problem. Only that one.